# Meaning of "-l" tag

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is meaning of "-l" tag?

For example:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) is quite clear:

> `'-l'` (is symbolic link)
>  Treats the TestString as a pathname and
>   **tests whether or not it exists, and is a symbolic link**. May also use the bash convention of -L or -h if there's a possibility of
>   confusion such as when using the -lt or -le tests.

Comment: What is iis web.config equalivant of this? Also, I'm trubbling to understand "symbolic link". Have you any additional links to documentations?

Comment: Symlinks are extremely rare on Windows—you don't even know what they are. Why would you want IIS to test for them?

Comment: because, I'm converting a .htaccess file from linux to windows format.